# XML merging two files does not work

Tags: xslt-2.0

I'm aware there are other questions that are similar to mine, but I wasn't really able to fix my problem, so I'm asking this wonderful community for insights where I went wrong. 
I'm trying to merge two XML files.

XML1

```
<root1>
    <element1 id="x">
        <subelement><element-i-want role="blubb">text</element-i-want>
            <element-i-want role="bla">text</element-i-want>
        </subelement>
    </element1>
     <element1 id="y">
        <subelement><element-i-want role="blubb">text</element-i-want>
            <element-i-want role="bla">text</element-i-want>
        </subelement>
    </element1>
</root1>
```

XML2

```
<root2>
    <element2 id="y">
        <subelement2>
            <title>
               Text
               </title>
        </subelement2>
    </element2>
</root2>
```

What I want:

```
<root2>
    <element2 id="y">
        <subelement2>
            <title>
                Text
            </title>
            <newelement2>
                <element-i-want role="blubb">text</element-i-want>
                <element-i-want role="bla">text</element-i-want>
            </newelement>
        </subelement2>
    </element2>
</root2>
```

The Elements  are supposed to be the granchildren of the element1 with the Attribute id="y" that Matches the id-attribute of element2

How I tried (XSLT 2.0):

```
<xsl:variable name="variable" select="document($xml1)/element1"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="title">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy> 
        <xsl:element name="new-element">
            <xsl:copy-of select="$variable[element/@id=/element2/@id]/subelement//element-i-want"/>
        </xsl:element>       
    </xsl:template>
```

What I get:

```
<root2>
    <element2 id="y">
        <subelement2>
            <title>
                Text
            </title>
            <newelement2/>
        </subelement2>
    </element2>
</root2>
```

Can anybody tell me, where I went wrong? I really don't get it right know. Thank you very much.

Comment: Well, if the elements have `id` attribute as your samples have and as your text explains then certainly the XSLT code checking `lawid` attributes doesn't make sense. Nor does the rest of your paths (e.g. `document($xml1)/element1` should probably be `document($xml1)/root/element1`). So test your paths step by step and correct them.

Comment: Working with two documents also requires you to store them both in a variable to refer to the other in a predicate or use `current()`, an intent like `$variable[element/@lawid=/element2/@lawid]` does never compare nodes from two documents, you need something like `$variable[@id=current()/../@id]`.

Comment: Oh, it was a typo, it should be id not lawid. I edited it. Thank you. And I'll try it your way and report back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would always define a key for cross-references but to fix your paths you could use

```
<xsl:variable name="variable" select="$doc1/root1/element1"/>

<xsl:template match="title">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy> 
        <xsl:element name="new-element">
            <xsl:copy-of select="$variable[@id = current()/../../@id]/subelement//element-i-want"/>
        </xsl:element>       
</xsl:template>
```

full example is at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxtqh (of course in your code you can use `<xsl:param name="doc1" select="document('file1.xml')"/>` instead of inlining the document).

With a key, using a literal result element and `xsl:next-match` you can simplify the code to

```
<xsl:key name="ref" match="root1/element1" use="@id"/>

<xsl:template match="title">
    <xsl:next-match/>
    <new-element>
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('ref', ../../@id, $doc1)/subelement/element-i-want"/>
    </new-element>
</xsl:template>
```

full sample is at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxtqh/1.

Online examples use XSLT 3 but in case of using an XSLT 2 processor you can simply remove the `xsl:mode` and keep your identity transformation template.